# Calling contact with arguments

Tags: stellar-core

How can you call a contract method with arguments. It's sad that the docs only focus on one scenario, calling a contract method without arguments. There are no docs on how to pass arguements to a contract method via stellar Js client.

I have been stuck with this for days. How can one pass arguements to a contract method via the the soroban js client.

It would be nice if an example of this was included in the docs